# How can I remove selected elements from xib file

Tags: xcode4.2, xcode4.4

I have create a xib file in xcode 4.2 or xcode 4.4. Now I want to remove some elements.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click to highlight the object in the view and press the delete key.

[image: IB1]

Alternatively, you can delete the object by selecting it in the view hierarchy.

[image: IB2]

You are going to want to make sure that you disconnect any properties that may be connected to the elements too.

[image: IB3]